# Express with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-async

I'm trying to return some rows from a db, connection works fine and everything but when express calls the function that retrieves the data it doesn't wait for the response.

I've tried many ways to write a callback to no avail, I've even tried using async (see code below), and it still runs all the way to the end before the data is even there. Any help?

```
router.get('/db/selectAllReadings', function(req, res) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(next){
      console.log('function 1');
      var rows = dbFunctions.selectAllReadings();
      next(rows);
    },
    function(next, rows){
      console.log('function 2');
      console.log(rows);
      next(rows);
    },
    function(next, rows){
      console.log('function 3');
      res.json(rows);
    }
  ]);
});
```

Comment: which function is fetching the data from the database.?

Comment: @ravishankar var rows = dbFunctions.selectAllReadings();

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed it to work, thanks to @imran khan for helping me see things clearer.

```
router.get('/db/selectAllReadings', function(req, res) {
  dbFunctions.selectAllReadings(function(rows){
    res.json(rows);
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
router.get('/db/selectAllReadings', function(req, res) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(next){
      console.log('function 1');
      dbFunctions.selectAllReadings(function(err,data){
        if(err){
        }else{
          var rows = data;
          next(rows);
        }
      });

    },
    function(next, rows){
      console.log('function 2');
      console.log(rows);
      next(rows);
    },
    function(next, rows){
      console.log('function 3');
      res.json(rows);
    }
  ]);
});

//need to do little bit change in your dbFunction

if (err) {
            callback(err,null);
        }
        else if (data.length > 0) {
            callback(null,data);
        }
```

i hope u will get an better idea of it..

Comment: While your answer didn't quite work, it help me understand things better and finally make it work, thanks